# how to transfer GPS device coordinates into mobile android app?

Tags: gps, android, geolocation

i'm trying to make an android app that collects data field in high accuracy, since the phone native GNSS doesn't provide highly accurate coordinates, i want to use Coordinates provided by a real GNSS device and transfer them to my app.

any way to do that using a real GNSS stand-alone device ?

Comment: Are you able to export the info collected from the GPS unit into a SQLite database?  If so, maybe the user can download that onto the device and [read it at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454031/android-reading-from-sqlite-database-at-runtime).

Comment: This may help a bit...https://github.com/ticofab/android-gpx-parser

Comment: you may want to look at the open source project that we built that does that: https://github.com/amigocloud/amigoclient

Comment: Be aware that both Android devices and "real stand-alone GPS devices" both have a wide range of accuracy, largely depending on the quality (and cost) of internal components.  In some cases Android devices will produce faster and better quality fixes that low end standalone GPS due to the use of assisted GPS.

Comment: I'm using Trimble R4 GPS, i think it is one of the most used devices in topography due to its accuracy.

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum do your project need accurate coordinates or just using phone GPS coordinates ?

Comment: @Elasri05GIS You can use a wide range of external GNSS receivers (or internal). If you really need to, you can get up to 2cm horizontal accuracy. The link I gave you above is the source code to our mobile application at http://www.amigocloud.com which is our hosted service.